# Will Nautilus Elementary be available for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus-elementary

I'm just used to Nautilus Elementary. Can I install it on Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the developer felt insulted by the Ubuntu developers after some comments at a UDS, and after the GNOME Developer rejected his patches (as they always do), so he stopped development of it.

You can use [Marlin](http://iloveubuntu.net/install-elementarys-marlin-ubuntu-1110-development-ppa) instead.

Comment: Technically he started it again for elementary Jupiter, but it has not been ported to GNOME 3.

Comment: @zpletan Jupiter is a bit old now. He's not working on it any more.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus Elementary is only for Nautilus 2.xx and probably won't be for Nautilus 3.xx but Elementary is working on a brand new file-browser called Marlin.

More information here: https://launchpad.net/marlin

Answer (score 0):

according to [ubuntuupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas/92) it isn't updated for oneiric but that doesn't mean it won't work so just try the instructions on that website and post back with results

Comment: Nautilus Elementary is only for Nautilus 2.xx and probably won't be for Nautilus 3.xx but Elementary is working on a brand new file-browser called Marlin.

Comment: @Evan I'd suggest posting that as a separate answer, ideally with linkified citations to sources (and, if separate, links to sources providing more information for people who are interested).